# Copy file from one DataLake Gen2 to another Data Lake Gen 2 via C# in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-private-link

I would like to do something simple!!!

Copy a blob from a Container (`SourceContainer`) which is in a dataLake gen 2 (`SourceDataLake`) to a second DatLake (`TargetDataLake`) via c# code in an Azure Functions.

The connection between my Azure Function and `SourceDataLake` is secured via Private Link and Private Endpoint.

```
DataLakeDirectoryClient sourcedirectoryClient2 = sourceDataLakeFileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(myPath);
DataLakeFileClient sourcefileClient = sourcedirectoryClient2.GetFileClient(myBlobName);
Response<FileDownloadInfo> downloadResponse = await sourcefileClient.ReadAsync(); //I get the error in this line
Stream reader = downloadResponse.Value.Content;

DataLakeDirectoryClient targetdirectoryClient = taregetDataLakeFileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(TargetDirectory);
DataLakeFileClient targetfileClient = await targetdirectoryClient.CreateFileAsync(myBlobName);

await targetfileClient.UploadAsync(reader, true);
```

for Authentication to DataLake I use this function:

```
public static DataLakeFileSystemClient GetDataLakeFileSystemClient(string containerName, string dataLakeName, string dataLakeAccessKey)
{
    StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(dataLakeName, dataLakeAccessKey);

    DataLakeClientOptions options = new DataLakeClientOptions(DataLakeClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_07_07);
    DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(
        new Uri(string.Concat("https://", dataLakeName, ".dfs.core.windows.net")),
        storageSharedKeyCredential,
        options);

    DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.GetFileSystemClient(containerName);
    return dataLakeFileSystemClient;
}
```

This code doesn't work for me. If I delete Priavet Link Private Endpoint from `SourceDataLake` then it works. Somehow Private Link and Private Endpoint doesn't work with this line of code:

```
Response<FileDownloadInfo> downloadResponse = await sourcefileClient.ReadAsync();
```

Do you have any Idea how can I solve this problem? or any better way to copy a blob from DataLake gen2?

Comment: Why not use AzCopy then? unless you have to read/modify metadata from each blob you don't need c# application

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cannot help with the current issue , but as you asked about other options , I think you can explore Azure data factory . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage